# Update Table with Aggregate function in where clause Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, updates, where-clause

I have TableA with the following data

```
 Name   A   B   Final
 Andy   1   1   2 
 Sam    1   0   2
```

I want to write an update query which will do the following:

1. If sum(A+B) <> Final then update row else do not Update

My Query

```
Update TableA
Set A = Case when Final in (1,2) then 1 else 0 End
Set B = Case When Final = 2 then 1 else 0
where final in (1,2) and **final <> sum(A+B)**
```

Since we can't use an aggregate function in update where clause I am not sure how to do the last part.

The query should only update row for Sam.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update TableA
Set A = Case when Final in (1,2) then 1 else 0 End
Set B = Case When Final = 2 then 1 else 0
where final in (1,2) and final <> A+B
```